# Importing Woocommerce Subscriptions from Wishlist Member Plugin - Failed Stripe Payments

Tags: stripe-payments, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have approx 400 members via Wishlist Member(Wordpress plugin - https://wishlistmember.com/) on my website that I'm trying to seamlessly migrate over to Woocommerce Subscription (Plugin - https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/). The Subscription plans are like for like and both using Stripe payment gateway.

I'm using a CSV file to do the import to woocommerce subscription via this plugin - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-subscriptions-importer-exporter

My issue is for the "payment_method_post_meta" field I require a "src_" payment method ID though for my wishlist member customers the payment id in stripe is a "pm_" payment id.

This is causing the next scheduled payment to fail. Is there a way to get a "src_" payment id for my customers so there isn't any intervention required on the customers behalf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal I was able to resolve this issue using WP ALL IMPORT PRO.

So firstly I imported the subscriptions with this plugin - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-subscriptions-importer-exporter
Though for the "payment_method_post_meta" field I wouldn't include the "_stripe_source_id".

Then I used "WP ALL IMPORT PRO" to import only the "_stripe_source_id"

[image: Screenshot of the wp all import pro plugin used to update a woocommerce subscription stripe source id]

I then used the following setup to ensure only the stripe_source_id was updated using the _customer_user custom field as the unique identifier.

[image: Screenshot of the import setup for importing the stripe_source_id to existing woocommerce subscriptions]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working with WooCommerce support on this. Looks like a few others have encountered issues with this plugin when trying to import card source objects:

- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-subscriptions-importer-exporter/issues/251
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-subscriptions-importer-exporter/issues/252

For additional context, the IDs for card details saved on Stripe can have one of a few different types of formats: `card_`, `src_`, `pm_`. Stripe's [older APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/older-apis) use `card` and `src`, while the latest [PaymentMethod API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) uses `pm`.

When using Stripe with a third-party plugin, it's ultimately up to plugin developers to add support within their tools for these types.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, when I manually update the stripe_source_id with the correct "pm_" id they scheduled payment is successful. The issue is that the somewhere between the importer plugin and the woocommerce subscription plugin. Even though the imfo is mapped correctly in my CSV it doesn't import to the required field within the subscription.